# why do these regex tests let certain characters pass?

Tags: c#, regex

I am checking a string with the following regexes:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
[A-Za-z]+
```

For some reason, the characters:

```
.
-
_
```

are allowed to pass, why is that?

Comment: How are you checking your string? Could you post the entire block of validation code?

Comment: You cold revert it with [^a-zA-Z0-9] and reject those that match that :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to check that the complete string consists of only the wanted characters you need to [*anchor*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your regex like follows:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Otherwise every string will pass that contains a string of the allowed characters *somewhere*. The anchors essentially tell the regular expression engine to start looking for those characters at the start of the string and stop looking at the end of the string.

To clarify: If you just use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` as your regex, then the regex engine would rightfully reject the string `-__--` as the regex doesn't match against that. There is no single character from the character class you defined.

However, with the string `a-b` it's different. The regular expression engine will match the first `a` here since that matches the expression you entered (at least one of the given characters) and won't care about the `-` or the `b`. It has done its job and successfully matched a substring according to your regular expression.

Similarly with `_-abcdef-` – the regex will match the substring `abcdef` just fine, because you didn't tell it to match only at the start or end of the string; and ignore the other characters.

So when using `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` as your regex you are telling the regex engine definitely that you are looking for one or more letters or digits, starting at the very beginning of the string right until the end of the string. There is no room for other characters to squeeze in or hide so this will do what you apparently want. But without the anchors, the match can be *anywhere* in your search string. For validation purposes you always want to use those anchors.

Comment: but why are the period/dash/underscore allowed?

Comment: @mrblah: Because `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` just matches against 1 or more of the characters in that block.  So, if you don't anchor it, as long as there's one of those characters, it passes the regex.

Comment: to mrblah: read your expressions as: find one or more symbols from a to z, from A to Z and from 0 to 9. So if there are any other symbols - don't care. ^ says that your symbols should be from the beginning, $ - at the end, and when you set both as Johannes - from beginning to the end and nothing else in between is expected.

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions the + tells the engine to match one or more characters.

So this expression [A-Za-z]+ passes if the string contains a sequence of 1 or more alphabetic characters.  The only strings that wouldn't pass are strings that contain no alphabetic characters at all.

The ^ symbol anchors the character class to the beginning of the string and the $ symbol anchors to the end of the string.

So ^[A-Za-z0-9]+ means 'match a string that begins with a sequence of one or more alphanumeric characters'.  But would allow strings that include non-alphanumerics so long as those characters were not at the beginning of the string.

While ^[A-Za-z0-9]+$ means 'match a string that begins and ends with a sequence of one or more alphanumeric characters'.  This is the only way to completely exclude non-alphanumerics from a string.